# jQuery UI resize child-elemets proportionally

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

Im searching for a way to scale child-elems proportionally. For better understanding visit

Here my code

```
$(function() {
    $( "#resizable" ).resizable({
        alsoResize: ".also"
    });
    $( ".also" ).resizable().draggable();
});
```

... or

http://jsfiddle.net/dF7WV/

This is my not-working version. Any ideas, how i can realize this with jQuery ui better?

EDIT: I am now 1 step ahead. Here is an version, which is near perfect. The init state is working perfect, but when i move one child, it looses the positin while scaling the parent elem:

http://jsfiddle.net/NNLg9/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#resizable" ).resizable({
        alsoResize: ".also"
    });
    $( ".also" ).resizable({
        alsoResize:"#resizable",
         containment:"#resizable"
    }).draggable({
        containment:"parent",

    });
});
</script>
```

Use the above script instead of yours

Comment: This not working too. The child elements must keep dimensions based on parent-element. Example: When Parent has 1000px 1000px and one child 200px x 200px. Now when i resize parent to 500px x 500px than the child elems must become 100px x 100px.

Answer (score -1):

Please Check this http://jsfiddle.net/dF7WV/10/
  or
Replace this

```
$( "#resizable" ).resizable({
alsoResize: ".also",
aspectRatio: 5/1
});
```